# Unexpected token '==' in object literal

Tags: javascript

I have created auto table but am getting an `Unexpected token '=='` error for some reason. I have checked if condition inside autotable parameter.

```
group1 = '1'
var i = 0;
if (group1.length) {
  i += 1;

  var res4 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('group3new'));

  doc.autoTable(res4.columns, res4.data, {
    showHead: 'firstPage',
    styles: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      fontSize: 5
    },
    if (i == 1) {
      startY: 30,
      margin: {
        right: 305
      },
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
      startY: 30,
      margin: {
        left: 305
      },
    }
    else {
      startY: lastAutoTable.finalY + 50,
      margin: {
        right: 305
      },
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what the problem? what you expected?

Comment: You cannot use `if ... else ...` inside an object, hence the syntax error

Comment: `var options = { showHead: ..., styles: ... }; if (i == 1) { options.startY = ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put if statements inside of object literal notation. When creating an Object you need to provide values only, to assure it's structure.

Any dynamic values should be added after, or computed before object creation.

```
 const data = {
    showHead: 'firstPage',
    styles: {overflow: 'hidden', fontSize: 5};
  }
  if (i === 1) {
    data.startY = 30;
    data.margin = {right: 305};
  } else if (i === 2) {
    data.startY = 30;
    data.margin = {left: 305};
  } else {
    data.startY = lastAutoTable.finalY + 50;
    data.margin = {right: 305};
  }
  doc.autoTable(res4.columns, res4.data, data);
```

Comment: Minor terminology correction - this is usually called object *initialiser* or *object literal notation*. Constructors is not incorrect but it's misleading because OOP has object constructors as a different distinct subroutine which creates objects.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out and completing my answer

Comment: how to print the 3rd table.finaly is not defined error

Comment: Is this still connected with current Question?